# Add existing entities to a collection from View Model - EF Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, collections, ef-code-first

I am trying to add existing users to  my Recipients collection in my MVC controllers CreateMessage action which passes a CreateMessageViewModel which should populate my domain Message object.

```
 public class CreateMessageViewModel
{
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> Recipients { get; set; }
}
```

Recipients are the posted user ID's I've selected in my view and the body is the message body.

My domain object is as follows:

```
public partial class Message : ModelBase
{
    public Message()  {
        this.Recipients = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SenderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SenderId")]
    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Recipients { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }                        

}
```

My controller action and respository is as follows:

```
UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork();

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Model.ViewModel.CreateMessageViewModel messagevm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var CurrentUserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

            MessageNotification message = new MessageNotification();
            message.Message = new Message
            {
                Body = messagevm.Body,
                SenderId = CurrentUserId      
            };

            foreach (int userId in messagevm.Recipients)
            {
                // How do I add the existing recipients here?
                // I get an exception here if I run this code and then save...
                User recipient = new User { UserId = userId };
                db.UserRepository.Attach(recipient);
                message.Message.Recipients.Add(recipient); 
            }

            message.Sent = DateTime.Now;
            message.UserId = CurrentUserId;

            db.MessagingRepository.Add(message);
            db.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(messagevm);
    }


public class Repository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class 
{
    internal MyDB Context; 
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public Repository(MyDB context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
        this.dbSet = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }                

    public virtual void Attach(TEntity entityToAttach)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToAttach);           
    }

    ............
}
```

How do I attach the user entities to the Recipients collection without fetching them from the database? I am using the same implementation of the repository pattern as stated in the [ASP.NET MVC tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) .

With the code above I get the following exception:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
var user = new User { UserId = userId };
db.Users.Attach(user);
message.Message.Recipients.Add(user);
```

You may want to check whether the user is already loaded in the context:

```
var user = db.Users.Local.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);
if (user == null)
... // create and attach user as above.
```

**Edit**

Your modification made me notice that `db` is not a context, but a unit of work. You could wrap the logic above in a method in `db.MessagingRepository`, like `GetUser(int userId)`.